# Spring - Autowired not working

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, autowired

This is my situation:
- /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">  

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.test.repository.user.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl" />

</beans>
```

- web.xml

  ```
  <display-name>Test</display-name>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```
- UserDaoImpl:

  `@Log4j2
  public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
   ...
   ...
  }`
- Test:

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:*applicationContext.xml" })
   public class TestDAO{

  @Autowired
  UserDAO userDAO;
  ```

  ...

  }
- pom.xml:

  ...

              org.springframework
              spring-context
              ${springframework.version}

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  ```

  ...
- Error:

  No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.repository.user.dao.impl.UserDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: try this `classpath:**/applicationContext.xml`

Comment: Not working....

Comment: I believe /WEB-INF/ needs to be at the beginning of your ContextConfiguration annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues unless you have defined the correct package name for `UserDAOImpl`. I just did the following setup and it is working.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.mytest.UserDAOImpl" />

</beans>
```

UserDAO

```
package com.mytest;

public interface UserDAO {
    public void mytest();
}
```

UserDAOImpl

```
package com.mytest;
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Override
    public void mytest() {
        System.out.println("In MY test");
    }
}
```

TestDAO

```
package com.mytest;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:C://<fully qualified path>//applicationContext.xml" })
    public class TestDAO {
        @Autowired
        UserDAO userDAO;

        @Test
        public void testSysout(){
            userDAO.mytest();//prints "In MY test"
        }
    }
```

Comment: If point to full path "file:C:\\....\applicationContext.xml" work! 
why does not it work with classpath?

Comment: its because `/WEB-INF/..` is not accessible from the test classpath. A simple problem. See the detailed description and solution [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/49585-how-to-get-contextconfiguration-using-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml)